# How do I make pyCharm stop hiding (unfold) my Python imports?

Tags: python, import, pycharm, code-folding

Every time I open a Python file PyCharm will hide all imports and shows:

```
import ...
```

within the editor.

I have to manually unfold it to see the imports. Where do I find the setting to undo auto-hiding of `import` statements?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-autofolding-behavior.html

Comment: Thanks! And I kept searching for "hide imports", "unfold imports", did not know there was a general setting for "code folding" :-)

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I really don't like the defaults on this IDE. Fighting "features" like whack-a-mole is really not my cup of tea.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

As this question may be useful for people who also are not looking for the term "code folding", I'll make my comment an answer.

As extracted from [IntelliJ IDE Web Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-settings.html), but also worked on PyCharm CE 3.4.1:

1. Open the IDE Settings (File > Settings, or Ctrl+Alt+S).
2. Under the "Editor" node, click "General" and then "Code Folding". The "Code Folding" page is displayed.
3. In the "Collapse by default list", select the check boxes to the left of the code constructs you want to be displayed collapsed. So here you can uncheck "Imports".
4. Apply changes.

The image below shows what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is now Editor > General > Code Folding, rather than just Editor > Code Folding

Comment: Thanks, that feature was super annoying

Comment: ... And "Collapse by default list" is now renamed to "Fold by default".

Answer (score 34):

[image: Pycharm 2016 settings]

Actually in pycharm 2016.1 it's Editor -> General -> Code Folding